# SQL Query to find the missing role

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query to find the companies that have the admin role missing. Below is the table design and the query should return the value `2` since the company 2 does not have a admin role associated with it.

Table Info - Company, CompanyRoleMapping(please assume companies 3,4 has all the 5 roles)

I tried this query

```
Select Company.COMPANY_ID
from Company inner join
     CompanyRoleMapping
     on Company.COMPANY_ID = CompanyRoleMapping.COMPANY_ID
group by USER_ROLE
having CompanyRoleMapping.USER_ROLE = 'admin'
```

[image]

But it doesn't seem to work. Can you please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Select the ids from your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT c.COMPANY_ID
FROM company c
WHERE c.COMPANY_ID NOT IN (SELECT crm.COMPANY_ID FROM CompanyRoleMapping crm WHERE crm.USER_ROLE = 'admin')
```

Tables

Company

```
Company_ID
1
2
3
4
```

CompanyRoleMapping

```
Company_id user_role
1          admin
1          manager
1          employee
1          client
1          technician
2          manager
2          employee
2          client
2          technician
```

Output

```
COMPANY_ID
2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07c28/1/0

Without Sub Queries

```
SELECT c.COMPANY_ID
FROM company c
INNER JOIN CompanyRoleMapping crm ON c.COMPANY_ID != crm.COMPANY_ID and crm.USER_ROLE = 'admin'
```

Output

```
COMPANY_ID
2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07c28/5/0

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort but Is there any way to obtain it without using sub-queries.? Else i'll have to go with the proposed solution

Comment: Try my second solution

Comment: Why can't you use sub-queries?

Comment: @Matt if there are no entries in CompanyRoleMapping table, the query with join doesn't return any result whereas the normal sub-query works

Answer (score 0):

Possible this SQL will be faster on bigger tables:

```
SELECT c.COMPANY_ID
FROM Company AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM CompanyRoleMapping AS r
    WHERE c.COMPANY_ID = r.COMPANY_ID
    AND r.USER_ROLE = 'admin'
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort but Is there any way to obtain it without using sub-queries.? Else i'll have to go with the proposed solution

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
SELECT C.* FROM Company C
WHERE C.CompanyID NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT CRM.CompanyID FROM CompanyRoleMapping CRM
    WHERE CRM.UserRole = 'admin'
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort but Is there any way to obtain it without using sub-queries.? Else i'll have to go with the proposed solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT C.COMPANY_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CM.USER_PROFILE) AS `profiles` FROM `Company` AS C INNER JOIN `CompanyRoleMapping` AS CM ON C.COMPANY_ID = CM.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY C.COMPANY_ID
HAVING (CASE WHEN `profiles` NOT LIKE '%admin%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6becc1/6